# How to launch EC2 instance via CLI in any availability zone?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm curious how I can ask to launch EC2 instance in any AZ, using AWS CLI? Currently, I'm using `aws ec2 run-instances .... --subnet-id subnet-xxxx`, where `subnet-xxxx` is one of the subnets for my custom VPC, located in a specific AZ.

But I want to be able to request EC2 in any AZ (due to `InsufficientInstanceCapacity` errors for certain EC2 types).

Answer (score 1):

The [run-instances — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html) says:

> If you don't specify a subnet ID, we choose a default subnet from your default VPC for you. If you don't have a default VPC, you must specify a subnet ID in the request.

Since your goal is to avoid receiving `InsufficientInstanceCapacity` errors, you might have to make your code 'more intelligent' by trying a subnet, waiting to see if there was an error and then trying a different subnet until an instance is successfully launched.

Comment: Thank you! It means - there is no way to 'launch in any AZ' if it's not default VPC...